QGIS graphical model builder - how to use multiple selected fields
While building a graphical model, I would like to select multiple fields of a vector layer. I am able to select these. As a second step I would like to use field calculator to get a new field which is mean of the selected fields in the previous step. If it is only one field , I am able to refer to it with the @input_name, but I am not sure how to refer to multiple fields selected in the same model @input_name (vector layer).
How can I do this?
